# what should be width of web site?

Tags: css

What would be an ideal (fixed) width of a general portal website? I noticed many websites have width from 960px to 1000px.

Comment: What does "General Portal" mean?

Comment: Subjective... Subject to closing :/ - Someone wanna make this Community WIki?

Answer (score 1):

While I think 960px is a good general answer I always like when websites use the most my monitor can display;

```
.wrapper {width:70%;min-width:960px;margin-left:15%;margin-right:15%}
```

This makes sure that the content is still centered in the screen but allows the layout to use the extra screen space if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the youtube, facebook - they have like 960px

Anyways, everything depends on site type.

Personally, I use 960px

Answer (score 0):

You really should be considering peoples display resolution.  You are better off designing your site for 1024x768 as this is one of the most common resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The width of a web page should primarily be based on the people who will be most likely to use it.

Are your users tech savvy? If so then they will likely all have 1024px or greater width monitors so 960-1000px would be appropriate.

If this is a site that has to cater to "everyone" i.e. a government site. Then you should probably also support smaller resolutions. 800x600 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

960px is the general consensus. It's based on an average screen size of `1024x768`, and the readability issues of super wide pages.

If you want to have a more fluid design for larger monitors, try something like [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com/), that's designed to scale to smaller sizes.